# Is it possible to change parent of WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to change the parent of a WPF control? Here is an example:

`StackPanel` stack1 has `Button` btn1 in it. There is another empty `StackPanel` stack2. I want to move the btn1 to stack2 programmatically.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via the [`StackPanel.Children`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) property:

```
stack1.Children.Remove(btn1);
stack2.Children.Add(btn1);
```

Comment: I'm attempting to do this with a grid, but it throws an exception claiming it is still parented when I try to add it to the new parent.

Comment: @prw56 have you trying to `Remove` children when the `Grid` have not loaded? if it is, you can check the `Grid.Children` it may empty, as we know that you cannot remove anything from an empty collection. `Grid.Children` is empty before loaded is caused by wpf visual tree lazy load feature. Just remove it after `Grid` loaded.