# WPF setting parent of label in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, label

I have being using winforms for a long time,
my project friends from university decided to change project forms to wpf. I have 3 questions

how do I set a parent of label?

```
labels[i].Parent = GroupLabelBox; (for my winforms)
```

Second createcontrol function

```
labels[i].CreateControl();
```

third one is bringtofront

```
labels[i].BringToFront();
```

Do you have any suggestion how can I determine difference on msdn which methods or parameters use for wpf or forms? (it would be nice for future cases )

Comment: For the first one :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222161/is-it-possible-to-change-parent-of-wpf-control

Answer (score 1):

```
yourParent.Children.Add(yourlabel);
```

as far as i know you cant set a parent but a children 
msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

for the secont part you can cange the ZIndex of your label:
[How do I bring an item to the front in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453613/how-do-i-bring-an-item-to-the-front-in-wpf)

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(yourlabel, 1);
```

msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.setzindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

to bring an label to the front i would just set the ZIndex to something low (i think lower means front, i may be wrong)